# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call, arcpy set parameter as text

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, modelbuilder, parameters

I have a python script loaded into arcgis ModelBuilder, and when I run the model I keep getting an error when the script tries to run, at the line where I am setting the output as a text parameter. The error is `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`. I've researched this error but still haven't figured out what the problem is? Here is my script:

```
import arcpy

mapFrames = r'C:\temp\temp.gdb\D04MapIndex_Master_MapSheetIndex'
fields = ['linkdir','mapdecade']
decadesText = r'P:\Records\GIS\__Databases__\MapIndex\decades_join_table.txt'
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0) = decadesText

with open (decadesText,'w') as f:
    f.write('dir;decade\n')
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mapFrames,fields):
        if row[1] is None or row[0] is None :
            print 'No decade or dir value, skipping'
            arcpy.AddMessage('No decade or dir value, skipping')
        else:
            print 'writing out',row[0],', decade value:',row[1]
            arcpy.AddMessage('writing out '+row[0]+', decade value:'+str(row[1]))
            f.write(row[0]+';'+str(row[1])+'\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the arcpy.SetParameterAsText() function takes two parameters: the parameter index position, and the parameter value. Rather than trying to assign the value to the function you need to provide it as the second parameter.

This:

```
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0, decadesText)
```

Not this:

```
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(0) = decadesText
```